# Regex in javascript for enum datatype of mysql

Tags: javascript, regex

I am working with php and mysql. I have one dropdown box where I am asking datatype of mysql field. Now, I want to put javascript validation for it. I am confused with the enum datatype. I am using regular expression `/^[']{1}[^',^\\]+[']{1}$/`. This is for one single value of enum values. It is working fine but issue is when I put single quote or backslash with backslash, it is valid but this regular expression shows it as invalid.

For eg, 'a'b' is invalid but 'a\'b' is valid.

Comment: You can write `[']{1}` as `'`.

Comment: You mean replacing `[^',^\\]+` with `[']{1}`?

Comment: No, replace `[']{1}` with `'`. They are equivalent.

Comment: You are all wrong. The canonical japanese smiley is (^_^)

Answer (score 0):

```
^'([^',^\\](\\.)?)+'$
```

`[^',^\\]` matches anything but the characters `',^\`. Following this, we match an optional `\.` which matches any escaped character (including `\.` and `\\`). We match one or more sequences of this pair, thus matching an `\'` anywhere in the string but not requiring it.

Note that in your regular expression, `[']{1}` means match one `'` character. This is equivalent to the literal `'`.

Comment: Can you explain me the purpose of four \'s. What is the need of string escaping? I got the need of regex escaping. So, for that only two are needed. :-( . Confused once again.

Comment: @himadri Read the second paragraph under [How to Use The JavaScript RegExp Object](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html).

Comment: @marcog If you're using the RegExp() constructor, you don't need the forward slash delimiters. They're used only for regular expression literals. If @himadri is using a regular expression literal, the double escaping of the backslash is not necessary.

Comment: @David Is that the preferred way in JS? Sorry, my JS knowledge is close to 0.

Comment: @marcog: The preferred way to express a standalone regex is without any host-language specific escaping or presentation. This means no forward slash delimiters and no double escaping. You can add these things when you provide a specific code sample, but if you don't, it's best just to write the regex and nothing else.

Comment: @marcog, thanks for your help. Though, your answer was not correct for all cases. It gives me hint and I got the answer. I am using forward slashes so no need for double escaping as @David says. My final regex is `/^'((\\')?(\\\\)?[^',^\\]*)+'$/` . Please, tell me if it is still wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @Tomalak Good advice, thanks. @himadri Is the \\\ correct? I think it should be \\. I've updated my answer with a simpler regex though. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: @marcog: The triple backslash is a result of a rendering bug that occurs exclusively for comments. See this question on meta that I just wrote for this very reason. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74340/backslash-escaping-in-code-regions-in-comments

Comment: @marcog they are actually four slashes. Also, your new regex is showing error when I test it at http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html .

Comment: @himadri Escaping issues. Updated answer, works on that site.

Comment: I don't think this regex works for successive escaped characters ie: `'es\c\aped'`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:  `/^'(\\.|[^',^\\]+)+'$/`
But, I would add whitespace fore and aft for validation (that can be stripped off with a   capture group)  `/^\s*('(\\.|[^',^\\]+)+')\s*$/`

Comment: this didn't work in `'\'a\'\b\''` should not match. But in your regex it match.

Comment: @himadri - My regex is: Quote (escape anything){1,} Quote - If we take out the anchor Qutoe's, your saying `a\'b` is valid but `\'a\'\b\'` is invalid? If yes then the only difference is the second one has a `\b`. Are you saying only `\'` is valid in the center?

Comment: Anybody care to show a full working example of validating a string like "enum('a','b','c')"